# How to port-wise redirect to https + port on Apache2

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I intend to setup multiple virtual host with same `ServerName` with different port numbers.

For example:

```
http://a.example.com:3001

http://a.example.com:3002

http://a.example.com:3003
```

I need to redirect to `https://a.example.com:3001` (https with port) and so on.

Can we write the condition like If port is 80+300X then redirect to `https//a.example.com:300X` (means `https+3001`) ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you expand a bit? On what condition exactly you want apache to do what exactly?

Comment: @Patrick I updated the question, please check again , if still any confusion pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could implement this sort of behaviour by listening to all ports and defining the 3001 port vhost expclicitly. Like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:3001>
DocumentRoot "/www/default3001"
# main app here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:*>
    DocumentRoot "/www/default"
    # do the redirect here...
</VirtualHost>
```

But you also need to set the server to listen to all ports you need. And there is no port range setup in apache httpd, so each port needs to be set up explicityly like this:

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
# lots of ports here....
Listen 3000
```

Comment: But here I've multiple ports for same domain; for  ex. if port `3001` then redirect to `https://<>:3001` and if `3002` then redirect to `https://<>:3002` and so on; Above will redirect for any request.

Comment: Ok... I've got no idea what is it that you're trying to implement... Can you clarify this by adding some concrete examples to your question.

Comment: First domain are same(`dev.example.com`) and ports are different(`dev.ex...:3001`, `:3002`, and so no) for diff. application running, here I need  to redirect to `https` like `https://dev.example.com:3001` and So on. Currently I open with `http` then get a `Bad Request` msg. So I've to redirect to `https`; I want to make condition like if `80+3001` then redirect to `https://<domain>:3001 and if `80+3002` then redirect to `https://<domain>:3002 and so on.